# How to color active tabs link in different color using css

Tags: css, tabs

i have a tabs, like that :
[image: one tabs]

And i want to color active tabs link in different colors, how can i fixe that using CSS.

The Static ID of each tab are:

1. tabInfosGen
2. tabDec
3. tabPiecesJoi

I tried this code:

```css
/* Color Tabs */  
/* -- Focus ----------------------------------*/  
#SR_tabInfosGen_tab .t-Tabs-link:focus {  
     font-weight:bold;  
box-shadow :0 2px 0 #336193 inset !important;  
}  
  
#SR_tabDec_tab .t-Tabs-link:focus {  
     font-weight:bold;  
box-shadow :0 2px 0 #1E8449 inset !important;  
}  
  
#SR_tabPiecesJoi_tab .t-Tabs-link:focus {  
     font-weight:bold;  
box-shadow :0 2px 0 #c03a2b inset !important;  
}  
  
  
*/ -- Hover ----------------------------------*/  
#SR_tabInfosGen_tab .t-Tabs-link:hover {  
     font-weight:bold;  
box-shadow :0 2px 0 #336193 inset !important;  
}  
  
  
#SR_tabDec_tab .t-Tabs-link:hover {  
     font-weight:bold;  
box-shadow :0 2px 0 #1E8449 inset !important;  
}  
  
  
#SR_tabPiecesJoi_tab .t-Tabs-link:hover {  
     font-weight:bold;  
box-shadow :0 2px 0 #c03a2b inset !important;  
}  
/* -- First Active ----------------------------------*/  
.is-active > .t-Tabs-link {  
  font-weight:bold;   
  box-shadow :0 2px 0 #336193 inset !important;  
}  
/* END Color Tabs */
```

```html
<ul class="t-Tabs t-Tabs--pill a-Tabs" role="tablist" style="white-space: nowrap; overflow-x: hidden;">
 <li class="t-Tabs-item a-Tabs-selected is-active" aria-controls="SR_tabInfosGen" role="tab" id="SR_tabInfosGen_tab" aria-selected="true">
  <a href="#SR_tabInfosGen" class="t-Tabs-link" role="presentation"><span>Informations Générales</span>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="t-Tabs-item a-Tabs-after" aria-controls="SR_tabDec" role="tab" id="SR_tabDec_tab" aria-selected="false">
  <a href="#SR_tabDec" class="t-Tabs-link" tabindex="-1" role="presentation"><span>Décisions</span>
  </a>
 </li>
 <li class="t-Tabs-item a-Tabs-after" aria-controls="SR_tabPiecesJoi" role="tab" id="SR_tabPiecesJoi_tab" aria-selected="false">
  <a href="#SR_tabPiecesJoi" class="t-Tabs-link" tabindex="-1" role="presentation"><span>Pièces Jointes</span>
  </a>
 </li>
</ul>
```

But it works at half, because when i lost focus, the box-shadow dont appear.

Comment: Please include the html to help others understand the issue.

Comment: i did it @jfeferman